# sum true boolean values from coreData array

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

the below code populates my table view value cells from core data. the otsBranch and Date values display. I am trying to figure out how to count the number of true boolean values for the records and display the number in the table cell as well. The let arr = ots function is my attempt to do this. But it gives me an error "Type OTSProcessConfirmation does not conform to protocol Sequence"

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return otsProcessConfirmations.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let ots = otsProcessConfirmations[indexPath.row]

    let date = otsProcessConfirmations[indexPath.row].otsDate
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .medium
    formatter.timeStyle = .none


    let arr = ots
    var trueCounter = 0
    for bElem in arr where bElem { trueCounter += 1 }
    print(trueCounter) // 3

    cell.textLabel?.text = ots.otsBranch
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = formatter.string(from: date! as Date)


    return cell
}
```

// the attributes in coredata with boolean values that I want to count the number of true.

```
         ots.otsQ1
         ots.otsQ2
          ots.otsQ3
          ots.otsQ4
         ots.otsQ5
         ots.otsQ6
         ots.otsQ7
          ots.otsQ8
          ots.otsQ9
        ots.otsQ10
        ots.otsQ11
         ots.otsQ12
         ots.otsQ13
         ots.otsQ14
```

Comment: Which boolean values? Does `ots` have a collection of binary values?

Comment: I added more to my first post that shows the coredata attributes that I want to count through to get the number of trues.

Comment: If I understand this correctly ots holds all the values from the record in core data.  "var otsProcessConfirmation:OTSProcessConfirmation?". OTSProcessConfirmation is the name of the entity. let ots = otsProcessConfirmation value is set by otsProcessConfirmation

Comment: So, to clarify, for each ots, you want the count of true values in otsQ1, otsQ2, ... otsQ14?

Comment: That is correct. I want to count the true values for each  otsQ1... otsQ14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is awkward, because your object doesn't have an array of values to process, just several similarly named properties.  I think the easiest solution is to build an array in code, and then process that:

```
let array = [ots.otsQ1, ots.otsQ2, ots.otsQ3, ots.otsQ4, 
             ots.otsQ5, ots.otsQ6, ots.otsQ7, ots.otsQ8,
             ots.otsQ9, ots.otsQ10, ots.otsQ11, ots.otsQ12,
             ots.otsQ13, ots.otsQ14]
let trueCounter = arr.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1 ? 1 : 0) }
```

That does mean that if you add another boolean, `otsQ15`, you will have to remember to add it to the array.